# Delete method skipped when on_cascade is triggered

Tags: django, django-models

I have this models:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    stock_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Component(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("quantity", "inventory", "unit_of_measurement")

    choices = (('cl', 'cl'),
               ('gr', 'gr'),
               ('kg', 'kg'),
               ('unità', 'unità'))

    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    unit_of_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=choices)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey('Inventory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Product.objects.filter(components=self)
        try:
            for product in products:
                product.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error {}".format(e))
        super(Component, self).delete()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} of {}".format(self.quantity, self.unit_of_measurement, self.inventory.name)


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=1)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    components = models.ManyToManyField('Component')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def composed_by(self):
        components = self.components.all().values_list('inventory__name')
        return ", ".join([component[0] for component in components])
```

The expected behavior is: If I delete a component, then all the products that contain that component are deleted. And this is ok. But when I delete an Inventory item, the component is deleted but the product is still there, just like delete method of component object is skipped. Any hint?

Comment: nope buddy. self is not iterable, what you wrote does not make sense.

Comment: what about self.product_set.all().delete()   ...Tell me if this works

Comment: I think that you misread the question. The problem is not the mechanism of delete method but the fact thet when an Inventary item is deleted, component delete method is not called.

Comment: so when you separately delete a component  , the products are deleting as it should?

Comment: you can try doing the delete by using the pre_delete signal instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> **Cascade deletes**. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.
>
> Model.delete() isn’t called on related models, but the pre_delete and post_delete signals are sent for all deleted objects.

So you can use `pre_delete` to remove all `Products` before your `Component` is deleted

```py
def remove_products(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    products = Product.objects.filter(components=instance)
    try:
        for product in products:
             product.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error {}".format(e))

pre_delete.connect(remove_product, sender=Component)
```